# error: conflicting types when cross compiling openssh for armv5tel

Tags: arm, openssh, cross-compilation

When cross compiling openssh-7.2p2 on wheezy for armv5tel, I get the following errors. `Before this, I have successfully cross compiled and installed zlib-1.2.8 and openssl-1.0.2h. For openssl`, I used as `./configure` command: `./Configure linux-armv4 --prefix=/usr/local`. Also tried with `linux-elf`, but got assembler errors.

When cross compiling openssh without openssl, there seems no issue

Any suggestion or idea, what I do wrong

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:107,
                 from /usr/local/include/openssl/pem.h:70,
                 from sshkey.c:37:
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:139: error: conflicting types for 'SHA256_CTX'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:72: error: previous declaration of 'SHA256_CTX' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:150: error: conflicting types for 'SHA256_Init'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:81: error: previous declaration of 'SHA256_Init' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:151: error: conflicting types for 'SHA256_Update'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:84: error: previous declaration of 'SHA256_Update' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:152: error: conflicting types for 'SHA256_Final'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:87: error: previous declaration of 'SHA256_Final' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:154: error: conflicting types for 'SHA256_Transform'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:82: error: previous declaration of 'SHA256_Transform' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:191: error: conflicting types for 'SHA512_CTX'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:77: error: previous declaration of 'SHA512_CTX' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:199: error: conflicting types for 'SHA384_Init'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:98: error: previous declaration of 'SHA384_Init' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:200: error: conflicting types for 'SHA384_Update'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:101: error: previous declaration of 'SHA384_Update' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:201: error: conflicting types for 'SHA384_Final'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:104: error: previous declaration of 'SHA384_Final' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:203: error: conflicting types for 'SHA512_Init'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:115: error: previous declaration of 'SHA512_Init' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:204: error: conflicting types for 'SHA512_Update'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:118: error: previous declaration of 'SHA512_Update' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:205: error: conflicting types for 'SHA512_Final'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:121: error: previous declaration of 'SHA512_Final' was here
/usr/local/include/openssl/sha.h:207: error: conflicting types for 'SHA512_Transform'
openbsd-compat/sha2.h:116: error: previous declaration of 'SHA512_Transform' was here
make: *** [sshkey.o] Error 1
```

Configure summary of openssh is as follows:

```
OpenSSH has been configured with the following options:  
                     User binaries: /usr/local/bin  
                   System binaries: /usr/local/sbin  
               Configuration files: /usr/local/etc/ssh  
                   Askpass program: /usr/local/libexec/ssh-askpass  
                      Manual pages: /usr/local/share/man/manX  
                          PID file: /var/run  
  Privilege separation chroot path: /var/empty  
            sshd default user PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin  
                    Manpage format: doc  
                       PAM support: no  
                   OSF SIA support: no  
                 KerberosV support: no  
                   SELinux support: no  
                 Smartcard support:   
                     S/KEY support: no  
              MD5 password support: no  
                   libedit support: no  
  Solaris process contract support: no  
           Solaris project support: no  
         Solaris privilege support: no 
       IP address in $DISPLAY hack: no  
           Translate v4 in v6 hack: yes  
                  BSD Auth support: no  
              Random number source:   
             Privsep sandbox style: none  
Host: arm-none-linux-gnu  
Compiler: arm-none-linux-gcc  
Compiler flags: -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all -std=gnu99 -fPIE 
Preprocessor flags: -I/usr/local/include  
Linker flags: -L/usr/local/include  -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,noexecstack -fstack-protector-all -pie  
Libraries: -lrt -lutil -lz  -lcrypt -lresolv
```

Comment: Did you cross-compiled openssl (and basically all the dependencies needed) before and pointed the configure to its `.so` and header files?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cross-compiled zlib and openssh-1.0.2h and installed it in /usr/local. For configuring openssh, used ./configure --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/ssh --host=arm-none-linux --disable-strip --disable-etc-default-login --with-zlib=/usr/local/include --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl --prefix=/usr/local --without-openssl-header-check.

Comment: This should have been in the original question. Can you compile it without openssl? (configure `--without-openssl`)? What is the whole summary of the `configure`? Isn't there still the link to your system paths?

Comment: Edited the question with more info. --without-openssl works and no errors. Added the summary of configure to the question.

Comment: That looks quite sane to me. I don't see any obvious flaw in there. But it looks like the configuration is not properly "inherited" to the `openbsd-compat` directory for some reason.
I saw some discussion about cross-compiling for [onenssh-unix-dev list](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/) some time ago, but I don't remember the conclusion.

Comment: Got it working. When using --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local instead of --with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl it works. Thanks for all help

Comment: Great to hear it. So it would be probably also helpful to see ssl path in the configure summary. Just an idea for a feature request ...

Answer (score 0):

The `--with-ssl-dir` option to the configure should not point directly to the `openssl` directory, but one level above (the includes are within `openssl` directory).

Configure with `--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/` instead of `--with-ssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl` makes the cross-compilation work just fine.